# NodeMCU Power supply

Tags: power, nodemcu, electronics

I got a question about externally powering my NodeMCU V3. It has an onboard voltage regulator (3v3) which breaks out to 3 header pins. Now I want to power 3v3 from an external board. Can I supply 3v3 to all of those pins at the same time? (Basically connected in parallel).
Anyone has done this before or has this experience with NodeMCU V3?

I have supplied a link below:
https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2018/10/introduction-to-nodemcu-v3.html

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may connect all `3V` pins together (red) and all `GND` pins together (black), like so:

[image: 3V pins connected together]

In some cases, more wires will improve the circuit. E.g. when you build the [Ben Eater 8-Bit CPU](https://eater.net/8bit/), you'll find that connecting power in a ring instead of a line will reduce voltage drop by about 50%.

---

When first reading your question, I got the impression that you wanted to solder the 3.3 V wires directly to the voltage regulator. Here's my original answer for that:

That's not a good idea: if you connect the same wire to all pins, your're creating a short, typically causing a malfunction if not worse. You may destroy your equipment (external board as well as the NodeMCU v3). Do NOT connect 3.3V to all pins of the voltage regulator.

A voltage regulator has 3 pins:

- voltage in (for an unregulated voltage you can't exactly control; typically higher than the output voltage)
- voltage out (for the stabilized resulting voltage you want to have)
- ground

The only pin to connect the voltage to is the "voltage in" pin (VIN). And typically, a development board has a pin for that:

[image: VIN pin on a 8266 development board]

However, you'll find that the [input voltage must be between 4.75V and 10V](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit-v1.0/issues/15), so supplying 3.3V from an external board is not sufficient.

If you have regulated (stable) 3.3V already, you can connect that to a pin labelled 3V:

[image: 3V pin on a 8266 development board]

Also, you need to connect the grounds (GND) of both circuits together (GND of external board to GND of NodeMCU), otherwise the current will not find its way back.

Comment: I don't believe the OP wants to short the regulator, but externally apply 3V3 to the circuit

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your replies!
Like Sim Son said, I would just like to externally supply the 3V3 pins with a voltage regulator. Would it hurt if the 3, 3V3 pins are tied together to the same net? Would it give me problems?

Comment: @sanrays10: yes, that's possible. I've updated the answer and uploaded an image where I did exactly that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just what I needed to know!